# redux request failed with status code 400(bad request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

i am getting an error "400 bad request" i can't find out what is my error
below i share my frontend and backend code..
i am also share my image error link that i came
[https://ibb.co/swQPgYG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3r5i.png)

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ backend @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

**todoschema.js**

this is a todoschema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength:32,
        trim:true
    }
},{timestamps:true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo',todoSchema)
```

**auth.js/router**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {addTodo} = require('../controller/auth');

router.post('/addtodo',addTodo);

module.exports = router;
```

**auth.js/controller**

```
 const Todo = require('../model/todo');
exports.addTodo = (req,res) =>{
  const todo = new Todo(req.body)
  todo.save((err,todo) => {
    if(err || !todo){
      return res.status(400).json({
          err : 'NOT able to store data in database'
      })
    }
    res.json(todo);
  })
}
```

> ################## frontEnd ###########################
>
> API  ==  http://localhost:8000/api/

here i fetch request from my backend

**index.js**

```
import {API} from '../backend'
import axios from 'axios'
export const getdata = (todo) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(`${API}addtodo`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            dispatch({
                type : 'FETCH_TODO',
                payload : todo
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

This is the todoForm where i add my todo

**todoform.js**

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import {
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Button,
    Form,
    InputGroup,
    InputGroupAddon
} from 'reactstrap';
import {v4} from 'uuid';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {getdata } from '../Auth'

//redux
import {connect, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {addTodo} from '../Action/todo';
const TodoForm  = ({addTodo}) => {

    const [title,setTitle] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getdata())
    }, []);


    return( 
  <Form>
           <FormGroup>
               <InputGroup>
                    <Input 
                    type='text'
                    name='todo'
                    id='todo'
                    placeholder='Your next Todo'
                    value={title}
                    onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType='prepend'>
                        <Button color='primary' onClick={()=>{
                            if(title === ''){
                                return alert('please add a todo')
                            }
                            const todo = {
                                title,
                                id:v4(),
                            }
                    
                            addTodo(todo);
                    
                            setTitle('');
                        }}>
                        
                            ADD
                        </Button>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
               </InputGroup>
           </FormGroup>
       </Form>      
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({

}) 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    addTodo : todo =>{
        dispatch(addTodo(todo))
    },
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoForm)
```

Comment: log `err || !todo` and share the output

Comment: https://ibb.co/mTNGGpk  ... here is my output link

Comment: Not from postma,Want it when you hit from Front End/react

Comment: in my application frontEnd and backend working propely but when i hit add button isn't save data in database don't know what is wrong  https://ibb.co/9WD9j6C

Comment: Thats why I ask you share `console.log(err || !todo)` when you hit it add button. Don't share postman.

Answer (score 0):

getData(todo) - action creator function require argument

```
export const getdata = (todo) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(`${API}addtodo`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            dispatch({
                type : 'FETCH_TODO',
                payload : todo
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

and you call it without argument

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getdata())
    }, []);
```